# trying update azure container instances with azure cli

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-container-instances, azure-container-service, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have an **Azure Container Instance**. *Now I want to update this Container*. I try to integrate the **Log Analytics workspace** and I have a **WORKSPACE_ID** and **WORKSPACE_KEY**.

I'm following this Azure [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-log-analytics) but it has only created Container Example. But I need an Update example.

Can anyone help me to update the Azure Container Instance? Or any example or any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Policy of the Container Instance Group should be 'Always' if it is 'On Failure' I think it may not work ...